# you have held broken packages

Tags: package-management, kde

when I type:

```
sudo apt install kde-cli-tools
```

I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-cli-tools : Depends: libkf5kcmutils5 (>= 5.2.0+git20141003) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any help please, cause I am a beginner in Linux mint, I was a Windows user in the past.

and I want to install KDE connect to my Linux mint, but that what happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

You must update before installing anything.
Optionnaly upgrade too.

`sudo apt udate && sudo apt upgrade`

In some cases using `aptitude` instead of `apt` may solves dependency conflicts.

`sudo aptitude kde-cli-tools`

Comment: i tried that but also the same problem, also, i tried to install another package, sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop    and also the same problem

Comment: Dde you tried the `-f` option on both commands? Or the `--full-resolver` on aptitude? In case you don't know, always look at the `man` to find the right options `man aptitude`